# How to create a tkinter quit button that works for all the functions in the class?

Tags: python, tkinter

Suppose I have a class and it has a lot of functions in it.
I wanted to create a quit button using tkinter that will work for all the functions in the class.

Is there any easy way to do it? Here is what I have tried.

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import time


def threaded(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        e = threading.Event()
        return thread,e

    return wrapper


class MyClass:

    @threaded
    def func_to_be_threaded(self):
        i = 10
        while i > 1:
            print("xyz")
            time.sleep(2)
            i -= 1

def stopbutton(thread,e):
    def _quit():
        print("Exiting...")
        e.set()#set the flag that will kill the thread when it has finished
        thread.join()
        root.quit()
        root.destroy()

    root = tk.Tk()
    QuitButton = tk.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)  # the quit button
    QuitButton.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
    root.mainloop()


my_obj = MyClass()
handle,e = my_obj.func_to_be_threaded()
stopbutton(handle,e)
```

It doesnt exit the function though

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  A quit button would normally just close the window, or otherwise cause the mainloop to exit, in which case no further functions from your class would be executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "work for all functions"? When you call tkinter's `quit` method it will stop the event loop. Usually this means the program will exit.

Answer (score 0):

Your threaded function does not check `e` (the instance of `Event()`), so why do you expect that the threaded function will be terminated when `e.set()` is called?

You need to pass `e` to the threaded function and check whether it is set. If it is set, break out the while loop.  I would suggest to pass `e` as one of the *"kwargs"* as below:

```py
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import time


def threaded(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # create the Event() object and save it in the kwargs
        e = threading.Event()
        kwargs["EventObject"] = e  # choose any keyword you want
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread, e

    return wrapper


class MyClass:

    @threaded
    def func_to_be_threaded(self, *args, **kwargs): # added *args and **kwargs
        i = 10
        while i > 1 and not kwargs["EventObject"].is_set():
            print("xyz")
            time.sleep(2)
            i -= 1

def stopbutton(thread, e):
    def _quit():
        print("Exiting...")
        e.set()#set the flag that will kill the thread when it has finished
        thread.join()
        #root.quit()  # calling root.destroy() is enough
        root.destroy()

    root = tk.Tk()
    QuitButton = tk.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)  # the quit button
    QuitButton.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
    root.mainloop()


my_obj = MyClass()
handle, e = my_obj.func_to_be_threaded()
stopbutton(handle, e)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I would not prefer the functions in the class to be modified in anyway except the decorator outside it. In your case you introduced the event.isset() to check. Is there any way where this or any other method can be incorporated in the decorator itself without changing the function within the class.

Comment: @dd24 It is your design to accept arguments in the class function because you have used `threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)` in your posted code, my solution is just using your design to pass the instance of `threading.Event` to the class function.  Also creating the instance of `threading.Event` is also your origin design.